# How To Download an Excel Object created with COM in MVC?

Tags: null, private, worksheet, excel

I have this COM object created:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

 private Application app = null;
 private Workbook workbook = null;
 private Worksheet worksheet = null;


        worksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "title ";

        worksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "row 1 header";
        worksheet.Cells[2, 2] = "row 1 header";
        worksheet.Cells[2, 3] = "row 1 header";
        worksheet.Cells[2, 4] = "row 1 header";

        var i = 2;
        foreach (var vm in model)
        {

            worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = "value";
            worksheet.Cells[i, 2] = "value";
            worksheet.Cells[i, 3] = "value";
            worksheet.Cells[i, 4] = "value";

            i++;
        }
```

Now that I have this Excel.Application object,
how do I do to send it to the browser so the user can download it?

Answer (score 0):

After you insert the Worksheets in your Workbook, you can save you Workbook and  response.redirect to destiny path.

...

```
workbook.SaveAs(@"~/YourPathName/ExcelFileName.xls",
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlAddIn8,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing);
```

...

```
System.Web.HttpApplication htt = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;

htt.Response.Redirect(@"~/YourPathName/ExcelFileName.xls");
```